# Finding the transformation matrix given points in space and their projections on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, homogeneous-spaces

[Description of plane and points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cdLV.png)

Given a set of non-planar points ($\rm\color{green}{P_i}$) in $\color{green}{\text{Coordinate System 1}}$, the projections of those points ($\rm\color{blue}{S_i}$) on the $\color{blue}{\text{Shadow Plane}}$ in $\color{blue}{\text{Coordinate System 2}}$, and the distance ($\rm\color{blue}{d}$) between the $\color{red}{\text{Light  Source}}$ and the $\color{blue}{\text{Shadow Plane}}$ given in the same scale as the $\color{blue}{\text{Shadow Plane}}$; how would one determine the positions of points ($\rm\color{green}{P_i}$) in $\color{blue}{\text{Coordinate System 2}}$? How many Point-Projection ($\rm\color{green}{P_i}$-$\rm\color{blue}{S_i}$) pairs would be necessary for a fully constrained solution?

Note: $\color{green}{\text{Coordinate System 1}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{Coordinate System 2}}$ are rotated, translated, and scaled.

Comment: These are very basic questions about perspective projections. A simple Internet search will turn up any number of answers to this.

Comment: Could you please point me towards the "simple internet search" results, because it seems I am unable to find any viable solutions. The problem may be more complex than you believe it to be...

Comment: Search for “perspective projection,” as I suggested. The problem is in fact rather straightforward and comes down to computing the intersection of a line and a plane after a coordinate transformation or two.

Comment: @amd Yes, it does come down to computing the intersections. Unfortunately, although the relative locations of the points (P_i) to each other are given, they are not given relative to the plane. Moreover, the location of the light source is also not given relative to the plane (it is only given on one dimension). Can the problem even be solved? Is the problem underdetermined?

Comment: You’re basically trying to calibrate the camera from known image and scene data. This is a well-studied problem, but a rather broad one as well. You might have better luck attracting answers if you narrow your question.

Comment: Looks like the problem is underdetermined :(. see two 2D solutions in the following images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BYwe.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTMxn.png

Comment: You can completely recover the projection matrix with $5\frac12$ point correspondences. From that, with some assumptions about your “Coordinate System 2” you can recover the image (shadow) plane. See chapters 6 and 7 of Hartley & Zisserman’s *Multiple View Geometry In Computer Vision*. When I get some more time I’ll sketch this out in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be viewed as a variant of what’s known as the *resectioning* problem: recovering the $4\times3$ projection matrix $\mathtt P$ from a set of scene-image point correspondences. You can find more detail on how to do this in any standard reference such as Hartley and Zisserman’s *Multiple View Geometry In Computer Vision*. Once you have $\mathtt P$, you can recover the information that you need to construct “Coordinate System 2” from it. In particular, you have the following:

- Writing $\mathtt P = \left[\mathtt M \mid \mathbf p_4\right]$, the third row $\mathbf m^3$ of the submatrix $\mathtt M$ is a vector parallel to the camera axis; $\det(\mathtt M)\mathbf m^3$ points toward the front of the camera. This gives you the direction of the Coordinate System 2 $z$-axis. Since you know the camera’s location (which you could also recover from $\mathtt P$) and the distance to the image (shadow) plane, you now also know the image plane. You could instead displace the principal plane $\mathbf P^3$ by the known distance to the image plane, but you still have to determine the correct direction in which to displace it.
- The first and second rows of $\mathtt P$, $\mathbf P^1$ and $\mathbf P^2$, are the planes that map to the $y$- and $x$-axes, respectively, in the image. The $x$- and $y$-axes of Coordinate System 2 are therefore the intersections of these planes with the image plane. The origin of this coordinate system is of course the intersection of the three planes. The directional ambiguity is resolved by examining the scene-image point correspondences or back-mapping $(1,0,1)$ or $(0,1,1)$, which is a more expensive computation.

If an image point $\mathbf x = (x,y,w)^T$ corresponds to the scene point $\mathbf X$, then the following relation holds: $$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0^T & -w\mathbf X^T & y\mathbf X^T \\ w\mathbf X^T & 0 & -x\mathbf X^T \\ -y\mathbf X^T & w\mathbf X^T & 0\end{bmatrix} \mathtt P = \mathbf 0.$$ This is a set of homogeneous linear equations in the elements of $\mathtt P$. Each point correspondence contributes two independent equations and $\mathtt P$ has 11 degrees of freedom, so in general one needs $5\frac12$ point correspondences to determine $\mathtt P$ uniquely. This can be reduced for your problem since you have other constraints on $\mathtt P$, namely the known camera center $\mathbf C$, which satisfies $\mathtt P\mathbf C=\mathbf 0$ and so is effectively another point correspondence, and the distance to the image plane. There are, of course, degenerate configurations for which the reconstruction is ambiguous, for example, if the camera and scene points lie on a twisted cubic or on the union of the image plane and camera axis. Hartley and Zisserman discuss these degenerate configurations in more detail.